# WPF c# Subscribe/Publish events mechanism using reflection - right or wrong?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, binding, prism

I want to achieve a simple Subscribe/Publish mechanism within a WPF application so i can subscribe to events from different places in the application specifying the event type and handler method, and then when publishing the event, my mechanism will call all the subscribed methods on the subscribers. I cannot use the RoutedEvent as I want to raise events freely without being forced to the visual tree.

I am able to achieve the above using c# reflection. But as I am pretty new to c# and WPF(coming from Java), I want to be sure that this is the preferred way.

Is It ??

Many Thanks,

Comment: You can use reflection (there will be a performance hit), but I'm not sure whether it's the best fit for you.  Can you give an example of what you want to accomplish?  Maybe some pseudocode?

Comment: Thank you. I was using reflection as i was not aware of the Action class which could be used to pass a reference to the method. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want the ["Event Aggregator"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd458915.aspx) pattern from the [Prism](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/) framework. Surely you can implement it by yourself, although I don't see why you might need reflection for it.

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! I have already implemented such, i just need to replace the reflection usage i did with the use of the Action class which could be used to pass a reference to the subsriber method.
Is 'EventAggregator' availble for download as a library? Or is it just a pattern? Thank you.

Comment: It's implemented in the Prism framework (see a link for it in my answer) which is available for download from codeplex.com.